# How can I do multi region browsing with NuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

In the near future, It's going to be needed that I implement multi region browsing. Is it possible to achieve that using `@nuxtjs/i18n`? I recently implemented multi-language browsing with that library, but I'm not sure if I can implement multi-region browsing with it too.

Let me know if I'm wrong, and if there is any other library that allows me to make multi-region browsing let me know too! Thanks

UPDATE: By region, I mean an implementation like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY7Cq.jpg

Comment: What is multi region browsing?

Comment: @kissu I have an image to explain that, but since people here doesn't like images I'm gonna have to explain it. Imagine you live in Austria and I live in Peru. You want to change the region of the web page to show information according to your location (maybe prices, new, etc)

Comment: Images to illustrate your issue are fine. Images of something that can be shown with pure text are deprecated. What is the difference for you between multi-region and i18n so? If you really want to decorelate the language and the region, you'll need to set a global variable like `region` and make conditionals in your `.vue` based on this.

Comment: @kissu it's something like this https://imgur.com/a/BdyfEeC

Comment: Yep, a variable in Vuex would be enough. :)

Comment: Only using Vuex? So I suppose I should store that variable that references something like the "current region" as a global variable.

Comment: Yep, you can do it this way!